# black toner in place of colour toner in Epson C1100

Tags: epson-workforce

Can I use a black toner in place of a colour toner in the Epson C1100 printer to get rid of error message "replace toner" as I only want to print in black and white

Comment: Variation on the theme, but essentially the same question: http://superuser.com/questions/860019/can-i-refill-monochrome-laser-printer-cartridge-with-color-powder

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a different question from that [above](https://superuser.com/questions/860019/can-i-refill-monochrome-laser-printer-cartridge-with-color-powder), if I understand correctly: @abby does not want to use the cartridge to print, just to eliminate the "replace toner" message.

In that case, what is needed is a new chip to reset the cartridge to appear full. There are [directions for doing so](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDyi9s6uZHk) online, and [the chips seem to be available](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/reset-toner-chip-for-epson-aculaser-c1100.html). There are also reset chips should the message to replace or [install the photoconductor](http://www.fixyourownprinter.com/posts/40815) appear, but the unit is still OK.